# Excel VBA: Match row data and delete

Tags: vba, excel

I have to complete a few account reconciliations every month that can be rather painful. Basically I run a report that returns all transactions in the account within the last 2 months.  This report is usually several thousand lines long.  Every transaction besides an exception or two should have a Originating TRX Type of "Reversing".  How this works, for example, is the accountant will make a debit entry to this account on 1/31/2016, and then set the reversing date to 2/1/2016.  An Identical entry will be made automatically on 2/1/2016 but it will be flipped to a credit entry so that the entry balance will net at zero between the two months, if done correctly.  However, without fail, the accountants will be careless and make the entry "Standard" and don't set a reverse date.  therefore, an outstanding balance is left in the account.  The purpose of my recon is to find these incorrect "Standard" entries that did not reverse, notify the accountant, and make sure that they make the necessary correcting entry.  The most painful part of the recon is getting passed all of the entries that were done correctly to find the few incorrect one.  below is a picture of what the report looks like:

[image]

the date ranges for this report are 01/01/2016-02/29/2016.  what id like to be able to do is loop through the "Journal Entry" Column and find a match like the one below:

[image]

You'll notice that the first transaction has a TRX Date of 1/31/2016 and a debit balance and its match has a TRX Date of 2/01/2016 and a credit balance.  this entry was done correctly and I can delete it from my report.  It would be ideal if I had a macro that would take care of this step for me as it is the most time consuming part. I've tried writing code for this but haven't come up with anything that works.  Below is my thought process.

```
DataLastRow = Sheets(DataSheet).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set JERange = Sheets(DataSheet).Range("C6:C" & DataLastRow)

For Each JE1 In JERange

'declare JE1's TRX Date
'declare JE1's JE #

Set SearchRange = Sheets(DataSheet).Range(Cell.Offset(1, 0).Address(False, False) & ":C" & DataLastRow)

For Each JE2 in SearchRange

'declare JE2's TRX Date
'declare JE2's JE #

'IF statement to check for matching JE #'s and Non-Matching TRX Dates between JE1 and JE2

Next JE2

Next JE1
```

I'd like to start off by highlighting the matches first.  any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If i understand you well, you want to get first and last date in a month. Am i right?

Comment: Basically, in the example above, entry # 30,676,153 is one entry with 2 parts.  the first part of the entry has a date of 1/31/2016 and second part has a date of 2/1/2016 which is the "Reverse" date.  If all accountants used this dating convention, my job would be a lot easier, but they don't.  what id like to do is find every instance like the one in the example and highlight it

Comment: So an incorrect result would only have one instance of JE number?

Comment: Well, sounds like you want to find duplicates in Jurnal Entry...

Comment: @mrbungle in a perfect world, yes.  however, if an accountant realized their error before I did and submitted a entry to reverse their initial incorrect entry, you can see how I would end up with two different JE #'s that cancel out each other

Comment: @mrbungle another issue worth mentioning is that a single JE # can contain several transactions. if you look above at the first picture, youll notice that JE# 30,238,463 has several lines

Comment: So really it's looking at a JE# and it's debit and finding it's corresponding credit?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just needing to find the ones with only one JE number this should help.  This will count the instances of the JE, put that number in another column and filter on "1"

```
Sub test()

Dim w As Range
Dim iVal As Integer
lrow = Range("C5", Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count

For Each w In Range("C5:C" & lrow).Cells
    iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C5:C" & lrow), w.Value)
    w.Offset(0, 1).Value = iVal  '<---change this offset to an empty column
Next w

'change this to filter on the column you set above in the offset
'change "fields:=2" to the field that shows the count
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C5").AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="1", VisibleDropDown:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to get "duplicates" based on this condition:

1. [`Credit Amount`] is equal to [`Debit Amount`]

For large data amount i'd suggest to use ADODB.Recordset, which will be much, much faster than any loop through the cells.

See example macro:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetSpecificRows()
'declare variables
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim oRst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sConn As String
Dim sFileName As String
Dim sQry As String

'on error go to error handler
On Error GoTo Err_GetSpecificRows

'get the current file name (containing this macro)
sFileName = ThisWorkbook.FullName
'define connection string
sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & sFileName & ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES';"
'set query statement
sQry = "SELECT A.[TRX Date], A.[Journal Entry], A.[Debit Amount], A.[Credit Amount]" & vbCr & _
        "FROM [DataSheet$B5:H20] AS A INNER JOIN (" & vbCr & _
            "SELECT [TRX Date], [Journal Entry], [Debit Amount], [Credit Amount]" & vbCr & _
            "FROM [DataSheet$B5:H20]" & vbCr & _
            ") AS B ON A.[Journal Entry] =  B.[Journal Entry] AND A.[Debit Amount] = B.[Credit Amount]"

'create and open connection
Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
With oConn
    .ConnectionString = sConn
    .Open
End With

'create and open recordset
Set oRst = New ADODB.Recordset
oRst.Open Source:=sQry, ActiveConnection:=oConn, CursorType:=adOpenStatic, LockType:=adLockReadOnly

'MsgBox sQry, vbInformation, oRst.RecordCount

'clear destination sheet
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("B6:E20").Clear
'copy data from recordset
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("B6").CopyFromRecordset oRst

'exit instructions
Exit_GetSpecificRows:
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not oRst Is Nothing Then oRst.Close: Set oRst = Nothing
    If Not oConn Is Nothing Then oConn.Close: Set oConn = Nothing
    Exit Sub

'error handler
Err_GetSpecificRows:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, Err.Number
    Resume Exit_GetSpecificRows

End Sub
```

Note: Above code is searching for the data which meet condition and copy these data into another worksheet in the same workbook. If you would like to perform delete operation, you'll need to create [ADODB.Command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

For further information, please see:
[ADODB.Connection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[ADODB.Recordset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[connectionstrings for Excel](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help!  I slapped this together pretty quickly and it works well:

```
Set JERange = Sheets(DataSheet).Range("C6:C" & DataLastRow)

For Each JE1 In JERange

JEMatch = False
TRXTypeMatch = False
TRXDateNoMatch = False

JENum1 = JE1.Value
TRXDate1 = JE1.Offset(0, -1).Value
TRXType1 = JE1.Offset(0, 10).Value

Set SearchRange = Sheets(DataSheet).Range(JE1.Offset(1, 0).Address(False, False) & ":C" & DataLastRow)

For Each JE2 In SearchRange

JEMatch = False
TRXTypeMatch = False
TRXDateNoMatch = False

JENum2 = JE2.Value
TRXDate2 = JE2.Offset(0, -1).Value
TRXType2 = JE2.Offset(0, 10).Value


If JENum1 = JENum2 Then
JEMatch = True
End If

If TRXDate1 <> TRXDate2 Then
TRXDateNoMatch = True
End If

If TRXType1 = TRXType2 Then
TRXTypeMatch = True
End If

If JEMatch = True And TRXDateNoMatch = True And TRXTypeMatch = True Then

  JE1.Select
  With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With

  JE2.Select
  With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
  End With

End If

Next JE2

Next JE1
```